# Выбор минимальное число из массива, с условием

Tags: php

Есть задача выбрать минимальное число из перечня в массиве (503, 2959, 115, 2899, 3000, 2775, 0). Но с условием, если самое минимальное число - **115**, и второе минимальное число в ряду - **503**, имеют разницу между собой более 15%, учитывать второе минимальное число - **503**.

В свою очередь если второе минимальное число **503**, имеет разницу с третьим минимальным числом более 15% - **2775**, учитывать третье минимальное число.

Число, которое имеет разницу с соседним минимальным числом менее 15% процентов, будет считаться нужным числом в ряду для переменной **$price_monitoring**

Работаю в php, сейчас выбирает просто самое минимальное число, без доп условии о 15%

```
$price_monitoring_nozeros = array_values(array_diff(array(503, 2959, 115, 2899, 3000, 2775, 0), array(0)));
$price_monitoring = empty($price_monitoring_nozeros) ? 0 : min($price_monitoring_nozeros);

echo $price_monitoring;
```

Comment: Ну отсортируйте для начала

Comment: @MBo сортировать массив для поиска минимума - такое себе )

Comment: вы напишите функцию, которая будет находить минимум, удалять его из массива и возвращать.. А потом while(true) и вытаскивайте миниумы пока нужное условие не будет достигнуто

Comment: @teran так себе идея, в худшем случае получаем результат не самой оптимальной сортировки, а вот искать минимум и сортировать попутно...  :)

Comment: @,teran В общем случае - да, но здесь неизвестное количество начальных элементов придется пройти, и уже надо оценивать - если их может быть порядка log(n), то с сортировкой будет не хуже, а код проще

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
$price_monitoring_nozeros = array_filter(array(503, 2959, 115, 2899, 3000, 2775, 0)); //without zeroes
sort($price_monitoring_nozeros);
$price_monitoring = empty($price_monitoring_nozeros) ? 0 : pos($price_monitoring_nozeros);
$price_monitoring = pos($price_monitoring_nozeros);
while (($el = next($price_monitoring_nozeros)) && $price_monitoring * 1.15 < $el )  $price_monitoring = $el;

var_export([$price_monitoring_nozeros, $price_monitoring]);
echo $price_monitoring;
```